# Issues with install/config Couchbase on Azure Linux RH7.4 VM

Tags: linux, azure, couchbase, redhat

I have created a RedHat 7.4 Linux VM in Azure in order to replicate our current couchbase marketplace server. We are moving away from this due to the inability to pay via invoicing.

I have installed couchbase-server-community-4.5.0-centos7.86_64.rpm and amended the swappiness, disabled THP and opened ports as suggested. The bucket name and password are also the same.

The staff member who created the marketplace VM is no longer employed here and there is no documentation.

When configuring the couchbase installation I have tried the public IP and DNS name but receive **listen EADDRNOTAVAIL**. I have also provided both the private IP of the VM and the 127.0.0.1 localhost address during configuration, both of which allow me to proceed. However, we are unable to insert data in to the bucket created and receive a timeout error when trying via a simple console app.

> InnerException    {"A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond"} System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}

I'm not overly familiar with Linux, so any ideas or suggestions are most welcome. Are there any system files I need to edit? Do I need to edit the host file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download `couchbase-server-community-4.5.1-centos7.x86_64.rpm`
 from the https://packages.couchbase.com/releases/4.5.1/couchbase-server-community-4.5.1-centos7.x86_64.rpm.

When you install the rpm you will get the following message.

> You have successfully installed Couchbase Server. Please browse to
>   http://shui:8091/ to configure your server. Please refer to
>   http://couchbase.com for additional resources.
>
> Please note that you have to update your firewall configuration to
>   allow connections to the following ports: 4369, 8091 to 8094, 9100 to
>   9105, 9998, 9999, 11209 to 11211, 11214, 11215, 18091 to 18093, and
>   from 21100 to 21299.

You need open these port on [Azure NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg) and firewall.

For NSG, you need create rules like below:

[image]

For firewall, add rules like below:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8091/tcp --permanent
```

For test, you could disable firewall, use `systemctl stop firewalld.service`
.

Then you could open browser, enter `http://<public IP>:8091`. In my example, it is `http://52.224.178.211:8091`.

---

Also, you could use Paas service Couchbase Enterprise on Azure, please refer to this [link](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/cloud/couchbase-azure-marketplace.html#topic_rfg_qjt_xs).

Comment: I had to insert an entry in the host file to avoid the timeout, those ports are open, so I can hit the couchbase server, but when I try to append via my console app, I get a failure status of "ItemNotStored".

Comment: @Hicki Could you show some error screenshots. I test in my lab, I did not meet your error log.

Comment: @Hicki If possible, I suggest you could use Paas service, couchbase installed and configured correctly, after you create it, you don't need do other thing. https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/cloud/couchbase-azure-marketplace.html#topic_rfg_qjt_xs

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi Shengbao, I'll edit my question once I get chance tomorrow to include the console application code and the results when trying to append to the bucket. I appreciate your efforts to help me!

Comment: Fine, if you have any question, please post here.

Comment: As the answer is helpful, I've accepted it. However my edit of the host file was also key to avoiding the initial timeout issue.